# Finding up values from different cells and storing them in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet. The data is stored like

```
Col1. Col2. Col3. Col4  Col5
_____________________________

A=123 B=456 C=789 A=INV Y=67
_____________________________

A=678 B=783 A=900 U=89
_____________________________

B=890 C=PO F=09
_____________________________
```

Now, I want to search in "A=" in one row. Point is to search "A=" in these 5 columns. And, if found, paste the value in Col6. If multiple "A=" occasion found, both the cells having "A=" must be copied into Col6 cell.

My COl 6 must look like

```
123,INV
678,900
```

I am only able to get first value into Col 6 i.e 123 in first case. How to deal with multiples?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Office365` then use below formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,MID(FILTER(A1:E1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A=",A1:E1)),""),3,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please what 3,3 means here?

Comment: `3,3` means extract data from position 3 to 3 character.